# content-type; charset missing a space

Tags: glassfish, jax-rs

Using JAX-RS and Glassfish 3.1.2 I am trying to get the charset added to the content-type.

I've tried a few of the answers on SO, but I have one issue:

```
@Produces(
{
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=utf-8",
    MediaType.APPLICATION_XML  + "; charset=utf-8",
})
```

results in a header like:

```
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8
```

However some other code (a Python library) requires it to be like:

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
```

(note the space between the ; and charset).

From what I can tell the space is optional, but the Python library (out of our control) requires it.

Any ideas on what I need to do to convince JAX-RS to spit out the space?

Comment: In the end I used ngingx to add the charset instead... sigh.

Comment: I've seen this problem too with mobile applications. I suspect that the carriers are stripping data before sending it to the device - in this case invalidating the response...